# Python - Crawl Result Ended Up with Error Messages

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to extract room price and availability data from *Expedia* using their `API`. However, the problem I encounter is that when the hotel has no room available on a particular day, error messages pop up.

The error message when I use `Print JD` based on the below codes is:

```
{u'EanWsError': {u'category': u'SOLD_OUT', u'exceptionConditionId': -1, u'handling': u'RECOVERABLE', u'itineraryId': -1, u'ErrorAttributes': {u'errorAttributesMap': {u'entry': {u'value': 8001, u'key': u'SUPPLIER_ERROR_CODE'}}}, u'verboseMessage': u'errors.supplier.hotel.nolonger; error from supplier; 8001', u'presentationMessage': u'***The hotel you selected is no longer available. Please choose another.***'}, u'hotelId': 447643, u'customerSessionId': u'0AB2902D-92F0-CC91-50D2-6AA567897340', u'@size': u'0'}
```

---

```
import urllib2
import requests
import md5
import time
import datetime
import json
import csv
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

#GENERATING SPECIAL KEYS FOR URL (GET)
apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #private keys, can't disclose
secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #private keys, can't disclose
cid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #private keys, can't disclose

hash = md5.new()
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
sig = md5.new(apiKey + secret + timestamp).hexdigest()

#Date and Hotel Variables
StartDate = '12/31/2015'
EndDate = '12/31/2015'
HotelIDs = '447643'

url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?apiKey=' + apiKey + '&sig=' + sig + '&cid=' + cid + '&currencyCode=TWD&hotelId='+ HotelIDs + '&arrivalDate=' + StartDate + '&departureDate=' + EndDate + '&room1=1'
res = requests.get(url)
jd = json.loads(res.text)['HotelRoomAvailabilityResponse']

Name = jd['hotelName']

for Rooms in jd['HotelRoomResponse']:
    Descp = Rooms['rateDescription']
    Avail = Rooms['currentAllotment']
    Rate = Rooms['RateInfo']['ChargeableRateInfo']['@nightlyRateTotal']

    print Name, Descp, Avail, Rate
```

How can I fix this problem?

Is there an easier way to extract the data using python as I think my approach is actually quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I am not sure why you are using beautifulsoup here.  You should try cutting it out and using `urllib2` and `json` like below.

```
url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/avail?apiKey=' + apiKey + '&sig=' + sig + '&cid=' + cid + '&currencyCode=TWD&hotelId='+ HotelIDs + '&arrivalDate=' + StartDate + '&departureDate=' + EndDate + '&room1=1'
jd = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```

Then for the error handling I would just use some `try` blocks such as:

```
try:
    Name = jd['hotelName']

    for Rooms in jd['HotelRoomResponse']:
          Descp = Rooms['rateDescription']
          Avail = Rooms['currentAllotment']
          Rate = Rooms['RateInfo']['ChargeableRateInfo']['@nightlyRateTotal']

          print Name, Descp, Avail, Rate
 except:
     try:
          Error = jd['hotelId']
          print "Error with " + Error
     except:
          print "unknown Error"
```